# VS2015 VersionControlExt always null

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vspackage

I'm having problems with the VersionControlExt object in my VSPackage. It's always null, no matter that I do, since I run VS2015. No problems with VS2013 so far.

```
VersionControlExt versionControlExt = dte.GetObject(typeof(VersionControlExt).FullName) as VersionControlExt;
```

dte is a DTE2 object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely there is a version mismatch (12.0 of VS 2013 vs 14.0 of VS 2015) with the assembly containing VersionControlExt that you have referenced in your project.

The "as" operator doesn't throw an exception if the cast is failing, so change it to the following and answer yourself the inline questions:

```
// Is the object null?
object o = dte.GetObject(typeof(VersionControlExt).FullName);

try
{ 
   // Does the cast work?
   VersionControlExt versionControlExt = (VersionControlExt) o;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it was the version mismatch.